# ¿numero aleatorio en una variable String?

Tags: java

Sabemos que para generar un número aleatorio en `Java` solo es:

```
int t = (int) (Math.random()*14+1);
```

Pero lo que yo necesito es que esto se guarde en un arreglo con una variable, pero el arreglo es de tipo `String`, ¿como puedo hacer que este aleatorio se guarde en esa variable `t` pero como tipo `string`?

Comment: Bienvenido Juan, que has intentado hasta ahora?... Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por [ask]. Nadie en la página resuelve tareas. Podríamos ayudarte a buscar errores o sacarte algunas didas, pero necesitamos tu código para poder ayudarte

Comment: prueba con String test = "" + t;

Comment: si lo he entendido bien, quieres guardar un tipo int en un String. Puedes convertirlo tal que: String cadena = Integer.toString(numero);

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = String.valueOf(Math.random()*14+1);
```

Si lo quiere guardar en un arreglo

```
String[] arregloString = new String[9];
arregloString[0] = String.valueOf(Math.random()*14+1);
```

Comment: Ojo, tu lo estas guardando como decimal y lo quiere como entero.

Comment: El `Math.random()` devuelve double, puedes transformarlo a entero con `String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(Math.random()*14+1).intValue())`

Answer (score 1):

Hola si lo que quieres es crear un numero que nunca se repita puedes usar  un sello de tiempo (como System.currentTimeMillis()) para generar nuevos datos.

ya que la clase Math.random a pesar que es aleatoria como lo dice su nombre si se usar los mismo parámetros de entrada puedes que se repitan los valores.

te dejo un ejemplo saludos

```
  String variable  = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
  String[] strArray = new String[] {variable};
  System.out.println("valirable "+strArray[0]);
```

en este segundo ejemplo, separo numero por numero y lo dejo en un arreglo de string saludos

```
String[] array = variable .split("");
  for (String string : array) {
       System.out.println("string :"+string);
   }
```

Comment: Muy buen apunte el tema de nombrar que pueden repetirse los números aleatorios, pero en ningún caso contestas a la pregunta. Faltaría ver cómo guardas el número aleatorio en un arreglo de strings que es lo que solicita el usuario que ha hecho la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por la acotación, no lei bien la pregunta, acabo de modificar mi respuesta saludos.